# how to fill the blank space when ads not showing

Tags: android-layout, admob

i looking to fill the blank space when ads not showing in my app.

the ads are working fine and showing when i'am connected with internet.

but when the phone is not connected with sure the ad won't show up

so the ads space become blank.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                     ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
    <TabWidget 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I think these days user don't use apps without internet. And admob ads take negligible data from data plan. So don't put anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
     @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
       AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
      adView.loadAd(adRequest);
      adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
      public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorcode) {}
      adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    });
}
```